# Can't add members to SSAS role through Visual Studio

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, ssas, sql-server-2016

I'm unable to add members to an SSAS role through Visual Studio. I can create a role in Visual Studio. I can add member through SSMS but cant add members through my Visual Studio project. The problem comes when I need to deploy my solution, all members added through SSMS disappear; hence, I need to solve the problem of not being able to add members through my project in Visual Studio. maybe I need to give Visual Studio some permission?

I expect to be able to add members through my SSAS Visual Studio project and when I deploy the project again the members of the role don't get affected.

Right now, when I click on the Add.. button nothing happens

[image: Snapshot of the Visual Studio]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have the same issue in Visual Studio SSDT 2017

My workaround is to hit "F7" on the associated role (or right-click and go to view code.) You'll see that the role is just XML anyways and you can easily add a new `<Member>` and `<Name>` Attribute

For example, here is the XML for my test role:

```
<Role xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:ddl2="http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2003/engine/2" xmlns:ddl2_2="http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2003/engine/2/2" xmlns:ddl100_100="http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2008/engine/100/100" xmlns:ddl200="http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2010/engine/200" xmlns:ddl200_200="http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2010/engine/200/200" xmlns:ddl300="http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2011/engine/300" xmlns:ddl300_300="http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2011/engine/300/300" xmlns:ddl400="http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2012/engine/400" xmlns:ddl400_400="http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2012/engine/400/400" xmlns:ddl500="http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2013/engine/500" xmlns:ddl500_500="http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2013/engine/500/500" xmlns:dwd="http://schemas.microsoft.com/DataWarehouse/Designer/1.0" dwd:design-time-name="7979a90c-d53d-4f48-8969-4bd239b43346" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2003/engine">
  <ID>Test Role</ID>
  <Name>Test Role</Name>
  <CreatedTimestamp>0001-01-01T05:00:00Z</CreatedTimestamp>
  <LastSchemaUpdate>0001-01-01T05:00:00Z</LastSchemaUpdate>
  <Description>Role for testing</Description>
  <Members>
    <Member>
      <Name>127.0.0.1\TestUser</Name>
    </Member>
  </Members>
</Role>
```

Comment: Hi Zachary, 

   Thanks for the workaround. One question though, in your example is 127.0..0.1 your network domain?

Comment: Hello! Yes in that example my domain is "127.0.0.1" which is my local machine. I just used that as an example for simplicity's sake. You could also use hostname, so in that example it could have been `<Name>localhost\TestUser</Name>` and it would have worked the same way. Hope this clears it up. Thanks!

Comment: Great, thanks! I will use this workaround while my IT support figures out the issue.

Answer (score 0):

The popup that should appear when pressing the add button is not from visual studio but from active directory. You might not have the correct permissions to open that window.

But why do you need to add members before deployment, is your deployment envrionnement the same as your production environnement. If that is the case you should look at your deployment process because roles shouldn't disappear from your database when deploying.

Comment: Hi Jelle, This is a solution that is being developed for the first time, there is no production environment. I need to give access to my project team so they can be testing the look and feel functionalities, validate structures, etc as we develop it.

 By your comments, it seems that it might be that the  SSAS service account does not have all the required permissions by default. I'll contact my DBA to check on this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I was with the same problem, but they released a new version to fix that: [Can't add user to SSAS role](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/615485/cant-add-user-to-ssas-role.html). So I just upgraded to 2.9.12 version, and now it's working as it should.

Answer (score 0):

Very weird workaround that someone might find useful so i post it here.

The add button did not react to being clicked.
To check if it is due to some lack of access rights i wanted to check if i can browse a cube and change the user.
So i browsed a cube WITHIN the SSAS project.
I used the "Change User" option in the top left and changed it to a AD User.
Browsing with the AD User worked.
After that i checked the "ADD" button in again and now it worked.

I can not explain why, but after changing the user the button works.
But only for the duration the project is opened.
Once you close the project and reopen it the button does not work anymore.